# How to watch winapi dll function calls with C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to write a program which should catch WinAPI dll calls, such as Registry reading/editing or file reading/writing.
I know that reading a registry record is done by using the RegOpenKeyExW method in the advapi32 library.
I've found a project which has the abilities I need in here:
 http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/
But  I've no idea how to write my own.
It seems that I cant find the correct search terms since I couldn't find any resource, or tutorial about how can I do it.
I know that it is a very complicated and I dont expect a full answer. It would just be awesome if I can just get one little tip or a blog entry which can give me a bit of clue.

Comment: FWIW, if you just need a tool to monitor other programs look at Process Monitor: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". Choose one.

Comment: @Griwes: The Win32 API is equally compatible with both, so it makes sense to discuss API techniques without distinguishing.

Comment: @BenVoigt, then tag it with neither. As simple as that, since API question isn't a language question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is ["hooking"](https://www.google.com/search?q=hooking%20win32%20api%20calls&oq=hooking%20win32%20api%20calls). There seem to be plenty of useful resources available through the linked Google search. You can start with CodeProject's guide:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed

Another invaluable resource is [Microsoft's Detours library](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm reading it right now and it seems this is what I needed.